# Finding a solution to a modular problem efficiently

Tags: equation-solving, modular-arithmetic, findinstance

I want to find a naïve hash function of the form `Mod[a x + b, 2^p]` which would produce a value less or equal to `v` for all `x` in `nn`. The trivial query gets quite slow already for small number of `x` and small values of `p`:

```
Timing@With[{p = 8, v = 53, nn = {7, 34, 110, 111, 232}},
  FindInstance[
   And @@ 
    Table[Mod[a x + b, 2^p] <= v && 1 <= a < 2^p && 0 <= b < 2^p, {x, nn}],
   {a, b}, Integers]]
```

> {8.24544, {{a -> 239, b -> 119}}}

Brute force search can be much faster:

```
Timing@With[{p = 8, v = 53, nn = {7, 34, 110, 111, 232}},
  SelectFirst[
   Flatten[Table[{a, b}, {a, 1, 2^p - 1}, {b, 0, 2^p - 1}], 1],
   Apply[Evaluate[
      And @@ Table[Mod[#1 x + #2, 2^p] <= v, {x, nn}]] &]]]
```

> {0.179039, {17, 190}}

Expected search time would grow in order $O(4^p)$, which quickly becomes impractical for larger values of `p`.

In short: what practical methods (apart from compilation, parallelisation, etc.) could speed up this sort of search on Mma?

Comment: Could avoid creating the big table and just iterate until a pair that works is found.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yep, iteration is an option, but I didn't care to write that variant for the small example. The core question is finding a solution more efficiently than with an exhaustive search, if possible...

Comment: Could you post a representative example that is large enough to make this iteration not feasible? I have a heuristic approach but I am not sure it will scale successfully.